# What’s the difference between Normal and Easy in Tiger! Tiger!

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-2

The *Tiger! Tiger!* mini game in Tora’s house has two selectable difficulties: normal and easy.

What’s the difference between normal and easy? Do you get better rewards on the higher difficulty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I have experienced, the only difference is that you don't take wall damage. Rewards seem to be the same regardless of the mode you play in.

I couldn’t find any source or patch notes to back this up though.

Comment: In fact, the only difference is that you don't take wall damage.

Comment: It looks like it yes.

Comment: I may be imagining things, but do you get a score bonus for playing on Normal?